# Get the last 5 minutes from log file

Tags: date, unix, awk, sed

Im trying to get the last 5 minutes from a log file where time format is like this:

```
2021-08-10 16:05:00,007 ERROR [com.] Cought an Exception (el) Index: 1, Size: 0
2021-08-10 16:05:00,018 ERROR [com.] Cought an Exception (el) Index: 2, Size: 0
2021-08-10 16:10:00,005 ERROR [com.] Cought an Exception (el) Index: 2, Size: 0
2021-08-10 16:15:00,002 ERROR [com.] Cought an Exception (el) Index: 1, Size: 0
2021-08-10 16:15:00,014 ERROR [com.] Cought an Exception (el) Index: 2, Size: 0
2021-08-10 16:50:00,008 ERROR [com.] Cought an Exception (el) Index: 2, Size: 0
```

I have tried below sed command which is working on another format but I get nothing returned when i run this.

```
sed -n "/^$(date --date='5 minutes ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')/,\$p" logfile
```

Tried many many different commands but cannot find one to work for this time format `2021-08-10 16:50:00,008`

Anyone help is really appreciated.

Also now I'm trying with awk but its getting some random lines which are not on the last minutes but somewhere on the logfile: (i only want to get the last X minutes)

```
awk -v dt="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %T,%3N' -d '-30 minutes')" '$1 " " $2 > dt' logfile
Raw Trap [OID=.2.6.1.4.1.5.1.2.4...
Raw Trap [OID=.2.6.1.4.1.5.1.2.4...
Raw Trap [OID=.2.6.1.4.1.5.1.2.14...
Raw Trap [OID=.2.6.1.4.1.5.1.2.14,...
Raw Trap [OID=.2.6.1.4.1.5.1.2.14...
Raw Trap [OID=.2.6.1.4.1.5.1.2.14...
Raw Trap [OID=.2.6.1.4.1.5.1.2.14,...
Raw Trap [OID=.2.6.1.4.1.5.1.2.14,....
2021-08-11 14:00:00,010 ERROR [com.] Cought an IOException (el) Index: 2, Size: 0
2021-08-11 14:05:00,010 ERROR [com.] Cought an IOException (el) Index: 2, Size: 0`
```

more input from logfile:

```
2021-08-06 14:24:16,137 INFO  [com.] Invoking Rule: (class path...)
Raw Trap [OID=.1.3.6.1.2.14, Sender=v, VarBind OID=.1.3.6.3, VarBind Value=0] --> Clean Trap [........
2021-08-06 14:24:16,137 INFO  [com.] InstanceStr=null
2021-08-06 14:24:16,137 INFO  [com.] site_InstanceStr=null
2021-08-06 14:24:16,141 INFO  [com.] deleting raw trap com.RawTrapid: 7291, oid: .1.3.6.1.4, time: 2021/08/06 14:2...
2021-08-07 00:30:12,495 INFO  [com.] Exporting with user Admin
2021-08-07 00:30:12,511 INFO  [com.] preparing for bundle export; retrieving all parameters with bundle id matching: 
2021-08-07 00:31:07,538 INFO  [com.] Exporting with user Admin
2021-08-07 00:31:07,538 INFO  [com.] preparing for bundle export; retrieving all parameters with bundle id matching: 
2021-08-07 00:31:07,573 INFO  [com.] parameters retrieved: 1001
2021-08-07 00:31:07,573 INFO  [com.] creating temp bundle export directory in: /var/tmp/_export2021/fullversion
2021-08-07 00:31:07,914 INFO  [com.] Deleting temp dir: /var/tmp/_export_Sat_Aug_07_00_31_07_CEST_2021
2021-08-07 04:00:00,115 ERROR [com.] Partition maintenance failed: exit code=1, output: ERROR 1507 (HY000) at line 26: Error in list of partitions to DROP
```

Comment: `sed` is looking for an exact match for the start of the range; `sed` is **not** going to do any sort of *comparison* of datetime stamps; for example, if you pass `16:45` to `sed`, `sed` is going to look for a row with the exact time of `16:45` and if, as with your sample data, it does not find that exact timestamp then nothing is output; `sed` is **not** going to run a comparison and print rows where the time is `> 16:45`

Answer (score 4):

You can compute date in required format in the shell and pass it as argument to `awk` to conpare:

```sh
awk -v dt="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %T' -d '-5 minutes')" -F, '$1 > dt' file.log
```

If you want to include milli-second part also then use:

```sh
awk -v dt="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %T,%3N' -d '-5 minutes')" '($1 " " $2) > dt' file
```

PS: This requires gnu-date.

Comment: That is only giving me the time 5 minutes ago but not working for the additional part on the end `,008`
date '+%Y-%m-%d %T' -d '-5 minutes'
2021-08-10 17:22:49

Comment: I have second part also in my answer that takes care of milli second part.

Comment: i try using awk as you suggest but is not giving me correct output., not the last 5 minutes just random lines from the logfile.
also i try with `sed -n "/^$(date --date='5 minutes ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %T,%3N')/,\$p"` with part of milli seconds, and returns empty

Comment: `sed` is not gong to help. `awk` will surely work if you have long entries of last 5 minutes in logs and **current time zone of shell same as the that of log file**. [Check this online demo](https://ideone.com/nwHzrG)

Comment: @Stacker123 stop trying to use sed for this, it's completely the wrong tool for the job for the reasons already stated by multiple people.. If you have input that anubhava's script doesnt work for then add a **minimal** example of that input to your question and show the actual command you're executing, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Thanks both. So im trying with awk but its getting some random lines which are not on the last minutes but somewhere on the logfile. Updated my question

Comment: @Stacker123: It is because those lines don't have any timestamp at the start. Can you try this command: `awk -v dt="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %T,%3N' -d '-5 minutes')" '$1 ~ /^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/ && ($1 " " $2) > dt' file`

Comment: this one returns empty.

Comment: It definitely works if your log files have data as shown. If you can provide a bigger sample input for which it doesn't work then I can surely look into it.

Comment: Thanks for your effort so far. You are correct, those lines don't have the timestamp same as other lines. I updated the question with some more input from logfile.

Comment: On your updated input use: `awk -v dt="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %T,%3N' -d '-5 days')" '$1 ~ /^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/ && ($1 " " $2) > dt' file` Here I used `-5 days` to make sure I get some matching lines. This gives me 12 lines in output on your sample input. You should also get same no of lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235924/discussion-between-stacker123-and-anubhava).

Comment: Sorry I am on mobile right now so can't join chat